# WiFi is hard blocked in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, iwlwifi, rfkill

I am completely new to Ubuntu world!! I have been trying to solve the wifi problem for a week without success.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

I tried to set the device up using this command:

```
 ip link set Device up # where Device is the name  of my wireless device I got via 'iwconfig'
```

I get the following message:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

I looked everywhere in my PC, there is no a physical switch to switch the wifi on and off. Besides, the wireless works fine on windows. My PC is XOTIC PC G34

Can any one help here?

Answer (score 0):

see the highlighted part in the attachment which means 'close wifi'.

[image]

Comment: It does not switch on from that menu. When I do it from  the network setting, the switch goes on, but when I close the window and check again I see it is back to off.